# Are LaTeX et al. languages or packages?

Tags: discussion

Are LaTeX and friends considered programming languages or packages?

I'm applying to a job and would like my employer to know of my LaTeX proficiency. There's already a list of programming languages (Python, C++, Matlab, ...) and a list of "packages" (Office, COMSOL, Matlab, ...) on my CV. In which list does LaTeX fit? Or should it be under another heading?

Comment: @tohecz Isn't meta reserved for questions _about_ tex.se?  Anders, to avoid this being closed you should probably rephrase your question...perhaps something like "Are LaTeX et al. considered "programming languages"?  If not, then how would they be categorized?"

Comment: @ScottH. I rewrote the question a bit.

Comment: The CVs that I have seen tend to list it with the other "programming languages" (but then they often include junk like Word or Excel there as well so this shouldn't be taken as too reliable).  Maybe a beautiful CV will speak for itself as to your proficiency!

Comment: @AndrewStacey Maybe I should use a default font so that they recognise I've typeset the CV in LaTeX.

Comment: "If you're going to use Comic Sans, at least hyphenate it correctly"!  To be honest, I tend to skip those parts in CVs anyway (but then I am a mathematician).  The question (as I would see it) is: what do you want someone reading your CV to deduce from this fact?  I suspect that seeing "LaTeX" somewhere on your CV is not going to mean a lot to anyone as there are no recognised proficiency levels so no-one will really know what you mean by it.

Comment: I might understand closing the question as off-topic, but this question definitely does not fit on meta.tex.SE, which is reserved for questions about the _site_.

Comment: @AndrewStacey on linkedin there is currently some "skill" initiative going on and a lot of people puttting there skills in (and get endorsed by others) ... and it is interesting that many claim to have LaTeX or TeX ... so not totally consider strange ... by everybody

Comment: This is definitely off-topic for meta, see [faq#questions] and [faq#dontask]. While it's slightly unconventional for the main site, I can see its merit. (Voting to close as _off-topic_)

Comment: I'd rename the CV section to *Languages*, so you can include a broader list. `:)` I've seen worse, like people including HTML as a programming language - language, yes; programming, no. `:)`

Comment: Your cv (and cover letter) should always be tailored for the job you're applying for. If there's a reason why you think you would be better for _this_ job because you're fluent in `TeX` then say so, either in the cv or the cover letter.

Comment: @EthanBolker: The question is about _where_ to write it, not _whether_ to write it.

Comment: I agree with @doncherry that this is off topic on meta, but actually reasonably on-topic for the main site. (Sorry Anders, we aren't usually this indecisive). To make it a reasonable main site question it the CV aspect of the question simply needs to be made into an example of why the main question "Are LaTeX and friends" a software suite or a language?" is sometimes a reasonable one to ask. (The debate about how a CV should be organized, however, is decidedly not on topic.)

Comment: I now migrated this question back to the main site. It is definitivly off-topic on Meta because Meta is for questions about the main site. General questions like this are on-topic on the main site.